# Sharepoint/WSS Reporting Services Integration woes

Tags: sharepoint, ssrs

after a number of failed attempts i seem to have successfully installed the Reporting services add-in to my WSS farm. However, I seem to be missing most of the enhanced functionality eg no report library template, no report center site template. the only additional functionality available is the report viewer web part.

background: 2 server WSS 3.0 farm with CA (Central admin) WFE (web front end) and reporting services addin installed on 1, and SQL05 SP2 with Reporting services (RS) and all databases installed on other. I have a VM environment set up and have rolled this back and repeated a number of times.

I have configured RS within CA and activated 'Report Server INtegration Feature'. Within the 'site settings' I have a 'Reporting Services' heading with a 'manage shared schedules' item/link, not sure if there should be other options?

I was of the understanding that to view reports within sharepoint i could either create a new site using the 'report center' template or add a report library to an existing site, neither of which seems available

I am at a loss as to what to do, as all online information seems to do with dealing with installation issues/errors, which i seem to have eventually got past

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like maybe the SSRS addin for SharePoint didn't get installed.
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=1E53F882-0C16-4847-B331-132274AE8C84&displaylang=en

In the AppMgmt section of Central Admin, you should have a "Manage Integration Settings" in the Reporting Services area if this was installed properly.

Here are 2 URLs that discuss the installation and features available:
http://netindonesia.net/blogs/kasim.wirama/archive/2008/01/01/integrate-sql-server-2005-reporting-services-into-windows-sharepoint-services-3-0.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepoint/archive/2007/02/19/microsoft-sql-server-2005-sp2-reporting-services-integration-with-wss-3-0-and-moss-2007.aspx